# how to use matrix or function in svg? and understand 3d

Tags: svg

in http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/ there are given matrix n function which can be used with svg, but no example, plz check section 14.2, i want to know how to use them?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't apply perspective transforms to SVG elements.  SVG doesn't support that.  However you should be able to apply perspective CSS transforms to the container of the SVG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a bit too vague, but to help I would point you at an [explanation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function) and [here for more svg](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-transformation.html)

I'm not sure if there is full 3d transform support for SVG atm.

Example... [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dq3R6/2/)

```
 <svg id="svg">
    <rect id="rect1" x="10" y="10" width="50" height="50"/>
    <rect id="rect2" x="100" y="110" width="50" height="50"/>
 </svg>

#rect1 {
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 5;
    fill: blue;
    transform: matrix( 1,2,3,4,5,6);
    -ms-transform: matrix( 1,2,3,4,5,6);
    -webkit-transform: matrix( 1,2,3,4,5,6);
}


#rect2 {
    fill:green;
    transform: rotateY(-75deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-75deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-75deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

I'm not quite sure of what browser support is like as a lot is changing atm, so mileage may vary.